# centre a group of floated divs

Tags: css, css-float, center, floating

I'm trying to centre a group of floated divs.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    <div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Parent {
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;

    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    clear: both
}
.Child {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TDq7T/

How would I get it so that the child elements are centred? I'm really stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    background-color:pink;
}

.parent {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.child {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TDq7T/2/

Basically, I removed the "float: left" and set the center align of parent;

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TDq7T/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    background-color:pink;
     display:table;
}

.parent {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;

}

.child {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
   display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```